# What would cause glob to list results twice?

Tags: ls, wildcards

System: Raspbian 8 on a Raspberry Pi 3

An errant space in a `sudo` command caused a bunch of system directories (`/bin`, `/etc`, `/usr`, etc.) to be moved into a subdirectory. I was able to fix it by putting the SD card in my laptop and using a commercial ext4 read/write driver to move the directories back, but since then, I've had this problem:

```
josh2112@jenna:/etc $ ls -l
<snip/>
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root    4096 Jul 29  2016 ifplugd
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root    4096 Nov 12 09:09 ImageMagick-6
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root    4096 Nov 12 09:09 ImageMagick-6
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root    4096 Dec 29 11:15 init
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root    4096 Dec 29 11:15 init
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root    4096 Dec 31 14:41 init.d
drwxr-xr-x  5 root   root    4096 Sep 20  2017 initramfs-tools
drwxr-xr-x  5 root   root    4096 Sep 20  2017 initramfs-tools
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    1865 May 27  2016 inputrc
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root    4096 Jul 29  2016 insserv
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     859 Dec  4  2012 insserv.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     859 Dec  4  2012 insserv.conf
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root    4096 Sep 20  2017 insserv.conf.d
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root    4096 Jul 29  2016 iproute2
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root      28 Jan  6  2015 issue
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root      28 Jan  6  2015 issue
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root      21 Jan  6  2015 issue.net
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root      21 Jan  6  2015 issue.net
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root    4096 Jul 29  2016 kbd
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root    4096 Jul 29  2016 kernel
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root    4096 Oct  1 15:45 ldap
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root   95742 Dec 29 11:16 ld.so.cache
<snip/>

josh2112@jenna:/etc $ ls -li issue.net
2097413 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21 Jan  6  2015 issue.net

josh2112@jenna:/etc $ ls -lbi issue.net*
2097413 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21 Jan  6  2015 issue.net
2097413 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21 Jan  6  2015 issue.net
```

Notice when I specify the name of the file directly I only see one copy, but when I use a star I see two copies.  I printed the inode number to show that they're not two physically separate files?

Some more observations:

- Not everything is duplicated, but it seems to be the majority of files and the majority of directories.
- The duplicates match in every detail, including inode number.
- This occurs in `/etc` only; the other directories that got moved then moved back appear fine.
- I used the `-b` code to show any nonprintable chars in the filenames.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** Still not sure what caused the original issue but `e2fsck` found & fixed a ton of things, and the duplicate entries seem to be gone.

**Edit 2:** The duplicates are gone *but the original are also gone* That's on me, I guess, for blindly answering 'yes' to 400 or so `e2fsck`-reported errors. Meh, it was time for a reinstall anyway.

I guess the thing to be learned from all this is to use the proper tools for the job. Next time I'll try Tiny Core Linux which provides a "Live CD" type of environment via SD card, loaded into memory, so I can repair the SD card directly on the RPi.

Comment: What shell are you using? if you believe globbing is the issue, can you use `set -x` (or equivalent) to see exactly how the command is being expanded?

Comment: What does `e2fsck` think of the file system? This could be a bug in the ext4 driver you used.

Comment: @steeldriver `bash`. Great idea about `set -x`.  It reveals that `ls issue.net*` expands to `ls --color=auto issue.net issue.net`!

Comment: @StephenKitt Wow. `e2fsck` found all kinds of problems -- bad block numbers, wrong reference counts, and some weird things like this: `Entry 'python2.7' in ... (2097153) is a link to directory .../python2.7 (2098948)`.  I will run an automatic repair when I can get back to the machine.

Comment: @josh2112 It would have been useful to post the results of the `e2fsck` as an answer so that it could help any future users who might have the same problem. As it stands, this (excellent) questions is likely to be closed as a *problem that can't be reproduced*. Don't be afraid to post (and accept)  answers to your own questions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan Sounds fair.  It likely is unreproducible, unless you use a skechy tool to try and repair ext4 filesystems from a non-Linux partitions. For the record, it didn't work -- blindly hitting 'yes' on 400 or so `e2fsck` reported errors had the side effect of removing the duplicate files _and their originals_, leaving me with an unusable root filesystem.  So as no useful knowledge came out of this question I'd vote for it to be closed.